# When calling a boolean from GameViewController() in GameScene(), it won't update my values

Tags: ios, swift

I have button in GameViewController that lives on my main game screen:

```
var gameScene: GameScene!

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    gameScene = GameScene()
}

@IBAction func butPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    gameScene.buttonPressed = true
    println("Pressed from GameViewController")
}
```

but when I do this from GameScene() update method:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if (buttonPressed == true) {

        println("Pressed from GameScene")

        buttonPressed = false
    }
}
```

I never can change the variable to true. If I `println("buttonPressed")` from update(), it always stays false. However if I print buttonPressed from within the IBAction, it will show as true. The variable change in GameViewController() isn't changing the boolean value in update() in GameScene(). Why?

Please help me

Comment: Is the GameScene that you create in GameViewController the same object as the GameScene that executes the `update` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make new class with this code

```
class Data {
    struct gameScene {
        static var ButtonPressed:Bool = false 
    }
}
```

Then make some changes in your code

```
var gameScene: GameScene!

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    gameScene = GameScene()
}

@IBAction func butPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    Data.gameScene.buttonPressed = true
    println("Pressed from GameViewController")
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if (Data.gameScene.buttonPressed == true) {

        println("Pressed from GameScene")

        Data.gameScene.buttonPressed = false
    }
}
```

You can call to this variable anywhere in your project with this code

```
Data.gameScene.buttonPressed
```